# How to apply rxjs operator depending on value from source?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm creating a page with multiple forms and I want to detect mousedown, focus and blur events on each of those forms.

Most of the times, they are emitted simultaneously (e.g. clicking on one form while another one is already selected, emits "blur" and "mousedown"). The goal is to process only one of them.

I created an Observable called interactions$ which emits values which are "Event" objects such as mousedown, focus or blur event.

I'm using pipe on that Observable and now I have two options for the operator:

- debounceTime(100) so that only the last of them is processed
- throttleTime(100) so that only the first of them is processed.

```js
      this.interaction$
         .pipe(
            debounceTime(100),
            tap(evt => console.log('processing event' + evt))
         )
         .subscribe();
```

Ideally, I want both mousedown and focus events to be processed over the blur event but the problem is that when interactions$ emits:

- "mousedown" is emitted before "blur"
- "focus" is emitted after "blur"

So, my question is:

Is there any way to apply either debounceTime() or throttleTime() depending on the source value?

EDIT:

This interaction$ is a Subject whose values are being emitted on this event handler:

```js
onFieldInteract(field: string, evt: Event) {
    this.interaction$.next(new FormFieldInteraction(field, evt.type));
}
```

where FormFieldInteraction is just a class with 2 string properties.

EDIT 2:

Basically I want something like this but I'm not sure if there's any rxjs operator for it:

```js
this.interaction$.pipe(
      // if event.type === 'blur',
      debounceTime(100),
      // else
      throttleTime(100),
      tap(evt => this.fieldInteract.emit(evt))
   ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Could you share code how did you define`interactions$` Observable? I think `merge` would do the work there, but you should first share how `intercations` looks like.

Comment: Can you elaborate you exact use case, why do you need to have `this.interaction$` to be emitting different type of events? Could your problem solved if you had different Observables for different type of events?

Comment: @GogaKoreli I have `this.interaction$`because I wanted to combine all 3 events into a single source so that I can debounce/throttle them and process only one

Comment: How do you emit these values? Did you think about the splitting all of three observables into the one with custom logic of merging?

Comment: @AndriiZelenskyi The "focus" and "mousedown" events come from the same component instance so they are already merged and they only emit one at the time. The "blur" comes from the same component (class) but a different instance so I can only merge it here.

Comment: @AndriiZelenskyi, the custom logic of merging should be similar to the one answered by Goga Koreli but it still doesn't work 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I think that we need to better think about our problem. I think this is not about just one simple operator, but the problem needs better approach.

I separated two cases, one where you receive blur and remaining events.

1. Look at `blur$`, since `this.interaction$` is first debounced and then filtered overall result is that you will always get correct blur event this way.
2. As for `remaining$`, here we have remaining events other than blur, throttled as you wished them to be.

Finally we merge both of them together to get your intended behavior.

Have a look at updated example:

```
const blur$ = this.interaction$.pipe(
  debounceTime(100),
  filter((event) => event.type === 'blur'),
);

const remaining$ = this.interaction$.pipe(
  filter((event) => event.type !== 'blur'),
  throttleTime(100),
);

merge(blur$, remaining$)
  .pipe(tap((evt) => this.fieldInteract.emit(evt)))
  .subscribe();
```

Is this kind of behavior you are looking for? Tell me and I will modify answer based on your actual needs.

Comment: Not quite because I don't just want to delay(). I want to debounce() so that the "blur" event is not processed at all if another event is emitted after the blur

Comment: Made an edit on the post so all can see better what the use case really is

Comment: there's one more situation in which that approach does not work. If the "blur" event" is emitted after a "remaining" event, it will still pass the filter and be emitted.